# UTF-8 Japanese and Hangul script gets space inserted between characters in terminal emulator/tty

Tags: c, utf-8, terminal-emulator

I have problems with printing Japanese and Hangul scripts encoded in UTF-8 in C. The program itself is trivial (I have omitted includes):

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t valid_utf8_string1x[] = "宇宙に飛びたい"; //uint8_t is used on purpose
    printf(valid_utf8_string1x);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it (on st, kitty or tty) every character is separated by regular space (code 32 dec), however copying it and pasting in (even in the same terminal window) or redirecting output to file (by `./program > outfile`) will get rid of those, yet `echo "宇宙に飛びたい"` (where string is pasted without spaces) or `cat outfile` will make them appear again, even if they are not present in the input. Every other script I've tested (Greek, Russian, Polish and Latin, Arabic) worked fine. How can I get rid of spaces being printed? They mess up my UI.
PS. I copied and pasted the space itself between characters to get it's code.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it's an terminal feature.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Others may have the same issue in the future. Thanks for posting an answer.